# LXDE Launchers are missing, But MenuLibre shows apps. How to regenerate Launchers?

Tags: lxde

Picture says it all.

[image: screenshot]

Since MenuLibre shows the apps in categories , is there a way to generate the launchers respectively ?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the LXPanel?  Lubuntu has Default applications for LXsession.  Make sure that the Launcher Manager is lxpanelctl.  I don't know how it could have been changed or deleted but I would check there first.  Also if your menu is empty look here, http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXPanel#Fix_empty_menu_in_LXPanel.  It will It will kill lxpanel, delete the current menu cache and start the panel again.